# Automatically index classes in a given package on startup?

Tags: java

I am writing a small processor. To store the functions, I am using a `HashMap<String, Command> commands`, which holds classes that implement the `interface command`. Those classes, along with the interface, are in their own package `Commands`

Currently, I am using a bunch of `commands.put(...)` instructions to fill the HashMap.

I would like to make the filling of the HashMap iterative, so that I can just create or delete classes that implement the `interface command` without having to worry about updating the HashMap. Is something like this possible without too much hassle?

Comment: Use a loop in your filling function that checks at each iteration if the corresponding `Object` implements `Command`: `if(x instanceof Command)`, do what you want with it and then add it to the `HashMap`

Comment: I would like to do that, but how do I iterate over classes that implement an inteface / classes in a package?

Comment: Apparently you can use `The Reflections Library`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/520339/6252134